# Can't publish stream on Wowza Streaming engine. Server creates and immediately destroy stream

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, stream, wowza

I have set up the Wowza Streaming Engine on the AWS with application name "live". I have opened all necessary ports for the Wowza on the AWS to receive and re transmit the video stream.

I am taking stream from NVR in the LAN and publishing the video stream from Ubuntu machine using FFMPEG with below command on to Wowza Server.

```
ffmpeg -v debug -i "rtsp://888888:888888@192.168.1.5:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1"  -acodec copy -vcodec copy -sn -f flv "rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live/channel1 live=true pubUser=un pubPasswd=pw"
```

It gives me following error after around 60 secs on the terminal.

```
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live/channel1 live=true pubUser=un pubPasswd=pw.
Parsing...
Parsed protocol: 0
Parsed host    : xx.xx.xx.xx
Parsed app     : live
RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 110 (Connection timed out)
rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live/channel1 live=true pubUser=un pubPasswd=pw: Unknown error occurred
```

So, I checked the Wowza server log for any clue and I found this.

```
2016-09-27  08:22:31  UTC   comment server  INFO    200 -   MediaCasterStreamValidator.init[live/_definst_]: Started
2016-09-27  08:22:31  UTC   comment server  INFO    200 -   ModuleCoreSecurity.onAppStart[live/_definst_]: Publish: AllowedEncoders: securityPublishValidEncoders:Wirecast/|FME/|FMLE/|Wowza GoCoder*|Lavf/|UA Teradek/|KulaByte/|VidBlaster/|XSplit/|PESA  
2016-09-27  08:22:31  UTC   comment server  INFO    200 -   ModuleCoreSecurity.onAppStart[live/_definst_]: Publish: block duplicate stream names : false
2016-09-27  08:22:31  UTC   comment server  INFO    200 -   ModuleCoreSecurity.onAppStart[live/_definst_]: Publish: RTMP Authorization: password file:/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/conf/publish.password
2016-09-27  08:22:31  UTC   comment server  INFO    200 -   ModuleCoreSecurity.onAppStart[live/_definst_]: Play: SecureConnection: securityPlayRequireSecureConnection:false
2016-09-27  08:22:31  UTC   comment server  INFO    200 -   ModuleCoreSecurity.onAppStart[live/_definst_]: Play: securitySecureTokenVersion property is missing, using SecureToken Version 1, play security enabled for RTMP only
2016-09-27  08:22:31  UTC   app-start   application INFO    200 _definst_   live/_definst_
2016-09-27  08:22:31  UTC   connect-pending session INFO    100 <incomming IP>  -   _defaultVHost_  live    _definst_   2.975   [any]   1935    rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    <incomming IP>` rtmp    -   unknown 1873157588  3178    3073    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    -
2016-09-27  08:22:31  UTC   connect session INFO    200 <incomming IP>  -   _defaultVHost_  live    _definst_   2.975   [any]   1935    rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    <incomming IP>  rtmp    -   unknown 1873157588  3178    3073    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    -
2016-09-27  08:22:32  UTC   create  stream  INFO    200 -   -   _defaultVHost_  live    _definst_   0.0 [any]   1935    rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    <incomming IP>  rtmp    -   unknown 1873157588  3297    3565    1   0   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    -   rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    -
2016-09-27  08:22:33  UTC   destroy stream  INFO    200 -   -   _defaultVHost_  live    _definst_   1.644   [any]   1935    rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    <incomming IP>  rtmp    -   unknown 1873157588  3347    3796    1   0   0   0   -   -   -   -   -   -   rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    -   rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    -
2016-09-27  08:22:33  UTC   disconnect  session INFO    200 1873157588  -   _defaultVHost_  live    _definst_   5.198   [any]   1935    rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    <incomming IP>  rtmp    -   unknown 1873157588  3347    3796    -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   rtmp://xx.xx.xx.xx:1935/live    -
2016-09-27  08:23:34  UTC   app-stop    application INFO    200 _definst_   live/_definst_
```

So basically the server authentication is done correct but server starts the stream and stops immediately.

Can anyone please give me some pointer to look for this error?

Comment: I don't remember if this works with Wowza but try with `-f flv  rtmp://[username:password@]server[:port][/app][/instance][/playpath]`.

Comment: @aergistal, I have already tried that method, but that returned me RTMP_0 packet missing error. So, I changed the command and provided them with `pubUser=un pubPasswd=pw`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your ffmpeg command is not sending the user agent string (c-user-agent in the access logs). This helps your Wowza server identify which RTMP connections are valid publishers.

The following line is identifying the valid agent strings configured in your Wowza server:

```
2016-09-27  08:22:31  UTC   comment server  INFO    200 -   ModuleCoreSecurity.onAppStart[live/_definst_]: Publish: AllowedEncoders: securityPublishValidEncoders:Wirecast/|FME/|FMLE/|Wowza GoCoder*|Lavf/|UA Teradek/|KulaByte/|VidBlaster/|XSplit/|PESA
```

But your ffmpeg command is sending an `unknown` agent string based on the logs. Try using the following in your ffmpeg command's output URL:

```
"rtmp://localhost/live/myStream flashver=FMLE/3.0\20(compatible;\20FMSc/1.0) live=true pubUser=myuser pubPasswd=mypassword"
```

It should pass an agent string that matches one of the valid encoders for your Wowza server.